# Lua dynamic nested tables add extra table

Tags: php, lua, nested, lua-table

ok I am trying to create a table in Lua dynamically, as far as Lua goes ill be the first to tell you i am an epic n00b, however in php i can create the lua table i need, the php code is:

```
<?php
$height = 50;
$widthl = -25;
$widthr = 25;
$depth = 3;

echo "tbm.offsets = { -- Facedir indexed +1\n";
echo " { --Facedir = 0 \n";
 for ($x = $height; $x >= -1 ; $x--) {
   echo "  { -- $x \n";
   for ($y = $widthl; $y <= $widthr; $y++) {
     for ($z = 1; $z <= 1; $z++) {
     echo "    { X = ".$y.", Y = ".$x.", Z = ".$z." }, \n";
   }
  }
   echo "  },\n";

 }
echo " },\n";

echo " { --Facedir = 1 \n";
 for ($x = $height; $x >= -1 ; $x--) {
   echo "  { -- $x \n";
   for ($y = $widthl; $y <= $widthr; $y++) {
     for ($z = 1; $z <= 1; $z++) {
     echo "    { X = ".$z.", Y = ".$x.", Z = ".$y." }, \n";
   }
  }
   echo "  },\n";

 }
echo " },\n";

echo " { --Facedir = 2 \n";
 for ($x = $height; $x >= -1 ; $x--) {
   echo "  { -- $x \n";
   for ($y = $widthl; $y <= $widthr; $y++) {
     for ($z = -1; $z <= -1; $z++) {
     echo "    { X = ".$y.", Y = ".$x.", Z = ".$z." }, \n";
   }
  }
   echo "  },\n";

 }
echo " },\n";

echo " { --Facedir = 3 \n";
 for ($x = $height; $x >= -1 ; $x--) {
   echo "  { -- $x \n";
   for ($y = $widthl; $y <= $widthr; $y++) {
     for ($z = -1; $z <= -1; $z++) {
     echo "    { X = ".$z.", Y = ".$x.", Z = ".$y." }, \n";
   }
  }
   echo "  },\n";

 }
echo " },\n";


echo "} \n";
?>
```

that code crates a perfect static lua table: but now i am trying to do it directly in lua, and thanks to another post on here i have a great start but the new problem is that when i assign a table into another table in lua it actually add an unnecessary additional table, the lua code i have is :

```
local tbmoffsets = {}
local facedir = {}
local unit = {}
local row = {}


            Z1=1
            for Y1 = 2, -1,-1 do
                for X1 = -1,1 do
                  row[X1] = {X = X1, Y = Y1, Z = Z1}
                end
              unit[Y1]={row}
            end

facedir[0] = {unit}


--additonal facedirs



tbmoffsets[0] = {facedir}
```

the output table from this looks like:

```
0: 
  1:           <------- unnecessary 
    0: 
      1:       <------- unnecessary
        1: 
          1:   <------- unnecessary
            1: 
              Y: -1
              Z: 1
              X: 1
            0: 
              Y: -1
              Z: 1
              X: 0
            -1: 
              Y: -1
              Z: 1
              X: -1
        2: 
          1:        <------- unnecessary
            1: 
              Y: -1
              Z: 1
              X: 1
            0: 
              Y: -1
              Z: 1
              X: 0
            -1: 
              Y: -1
              Z: 1
              X: -1
        0: 
          1:    <------- unnecessary
            1: 
              Y: -1
              Z: 1
              X: 1
            0: 
              Y: -1
              Z: 1
              X: 0
            -1: 
              Y: -1
              Z: 1
              X: -1
        -1: 
          1: 
            1: 
              Y: -1
              Z: 1
              X: 1
            0: 
              Y: -1
              Z: 1
              X: 0
            -1: 
              Y: -1
              Z: 1
              X: -1
```

i marked where it is automatically putting in <------- unnecessary tables, can some one explain why it does this?

ok i figured it out, but my rep aint high enough to answer my own question... so heres the answer

```
            Z1=1
            for Y1 = 2, -1,-1 do
                for X1 = -1,1 do
                  row[X1] = {X = X1, Y = Y1, Z = Z1}
                end
              unit[Y1]={row} <--- these parentheses create the extra table 
            end

facedir[0] = {unit}   <--- these parentheses create the extra table


--additonal facedirs



tbmoffsets[0] = {facedir}  <--- these parentheses create the extra table
```

sometimes i guess you are your own best mentor...lmao

Comment: ok i figured it out

            Z1=1
            for Y1 = 2, -1,-1 do
                for X1 = -1,1 do
                  row[X1] = {X = X1, Y = Y1, Z = Z1}
                end
              unit[Y1]={row} <--- these parentheses create the extra table 
            end

facedir[0] = {unit}   <--- these parentheses create the extra table


--additonal facedirs



tbmoffsets[0] = {facedir}  <--- these parentheses create the extra table

sometimes i guess you are your own best mentor...lmao

Comment: Great that you found answer but you should either create an answer and accept it so this is closed, or reword question to be more specific if still have question, or delete your post if no longer pertinent.

Comment: i cant answer it until 5pm today... 8 hours or something like that. i would delete it but maybe someone else has the same "unintellegent beginner blunder" :) i will come back after 5 today and answer it so that it gets closed out :)